# Get Counts per Hour for all Dates

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get the total number of updates i receive hourly for all dates in my table. How can i achieve that ? This is what i have been trying but it doesn't return the expected.

My table name is `Updates` which has a field called `Time`. `Time` field is as such :

```
2013-09-02 21:00:01
```

So i want to get all the updates received for each hour for all days.

```
SELECT COUNT(Hour(Time)),Date(Time)  FROM update_detail GROUP BY Date(Time)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try below query, which will provide you hourly report:

```
SELECT 
date(`Time`) as 'Report_Date', hour(`Time`) AS Report_Hour,COUNT(id) AS 'Hourly_Count' 
FROM update_detail 
GROUP BY left(`Time`,13);
```

Comment: only GROUP BY  HOUR(`Time`) can also increase COUNTS with different dates but same hour. isn't it?

Comment: Your left(`time`,13) gives 2013-09-02 21. how can you consider as HOURS?

Comment: it is showing 9 pm, this is just solution for user he/she can format as per his/her requirement if want date in separate column and hour in separate then can do accordingly...but -ve voting should not be for it..

Comment: @llesh Patel: Don't mind dear...thanks you draw my attention on it, now I have corrected which is more presentable..thanks.

Comment: I saw left function for first time, its better than my answer where I call 2 functions to do grouping

Comment: @AkshayRansing: Thanks dear for your comment.

Comment: @ZafarMalik but you must admit its not self explanatory :) , may be because left is string function and not date time

Comment: Yes it is not datetime function but I use it as get my solution with single function, which seems better than using 2 different function.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
COUNT(*) as 'Rep_Count',Hour(Time) as 'Rep_Hour',Date(Time) as 'Rep_Date'
FROM update_detail 
GROUP BY HOUR(Time),DATE(Time);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please include an explanation for your code, as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Check it out MySQL function `DATE_FORMAT`.

```
SELECT
   DATE_FORMAT(Time, "%Y-%m-%d %H") date_by_hour, COUNT(*)
FROM
   update_detail
GROUP BY
   date_by_hour;
```